# Getting this error while running a systemd service

Tags: linux, liquibase, corda

[ERROR] 05:24:00+0100 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not create the DataSource: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE PUBLIC.DATABASECHHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '172.18.0.1 (172.18.0.1)', LOCKGRANTED = '2019-04-03 05:23:18.603' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE: The database is read only; SQL statement:

where should i run the update query to set locked = false in the server?

Comment: Yeah but it clearly states "The database is read only" so your service probably don't have enough permissions to set this flag.

Comment: i am using h2 db

Comment: Any ideas how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It is said in error message that your database is in readonly mode. To allow liquibase to apply updates you have to enable the write (and most likely delete) permissions. For H2 it's done by adding the `ACCESS_MODE_DATA=rws` parameter to url like that: `jdbc:h2:~/test;ACCESS_MODE_DATA=rws` ([H2 docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#custom_access_mode), [Corda docs](https://docs.corda.net/head/node-database-access-h2.html#connecting-to-the-database))

Comment: Where do I write this @mikhail?

Comment: I have no experience with corda but there's some info on database connection configuration in the docs: https://docs.corda.net/head/node-database-access-h2.html#connecting-to-the-database Though that problem of yours is not about liquibase, linux nor systemd.

Comment: No man I am just asking the command that you gave me where do I have to add it?

Comment: I get this error when I run sudo systemctl enable --now my_service. Do I need to add it in my .service

Comment: That's not a command, that's a property which must be read by corda during initialisation. It must be set somewhere in configs

Answer (score 0):

However it's very late,
Maybe you have copied cordapp files from another location or previously have run the node by other user. Therefore, delete these files and directories:
persistence.mv.db ,
persistence.trace.db ,
additional-node-infos ,
artemis ,
brokers ,
capsule ,
drivers